# Is pict2e a replacement for picture?

Tags: diagrams

I'm confused by the role the `pict2e` package plays vis-a-vis the `picture` package. I used to believe that it is an enhanced replacement, but that's obviously not the case as the following example compiles with `picture` but not with `pict2e` in both, pdflatex and xelatex:

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{report}

\usepackage{picture}
\usepackage{eso-pic}

\usepackage{fp-basic}
\usepackage[cam,noinfo,center]{crop}

\usepackage{tikz}

\AddToShipoutPictureBG{%
    \put(1cm,1cm){%
        \tikz\node[rectangle, minimum height=2cm, minimum width=2cm, draw=black, fill=black] {};%
    }%
}%

\begin{document}
Hello World!
\end{document}
```

Can someone please enlighten me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you read the documents of [`pict2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pict2e) and [`picture`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/picture) packages?

`pict2e` package is new implementation of LaTeX's `picture` *environment*. (NOT the `picture` *package* by Oberdiek).

`picture` package supports the syntax such as `\put(2cm,2cm)` instead of original `\setlength{\unitlength}{1cm}` and `\put(2,2)`.

The two packages are totally different.

And read this in the document of `picture` package:

> Packages `pspicture` and `pict2e` are supported, but they must be loaded before package `picture`.

Comment: Thanks. I did read the documents but I really confused myself over _environment_ vs _package_. Confusion solved.